# How to pod download by name only?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have created a Pod of my own. But I cant seem to download the Pod through

```
pod 'MyFramework'
```

I have to specify

```
pod 'MyFramework', git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
```

Is there any thing I can do, so that I can download the Pod by name alone?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a private pod or a public one?

Comment: @Larme I believe it is public? I did not pay any money

Comment: Have you sent your library to the pod specs repo as described [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) under 'Submitting open source code'?

Comment: @ScriptableI don think so, thank! I will follow the answer and see how it goes (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to submit your library to the Specs Repo.

**You could read these:**

What is a Spec Repo:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html#how-does-the-specs-repo-work

Submitting your library to the Spec Repo

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html#submitting-open-source-code

Creating a Cocoa Pods trunk account for submission

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/getting-setup-with-trunk

Basically all this in your pod file that doesn't have a git url attach to it. Its being looked up on a Spec Repo.

Example:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
```

CocoaPods will look into the Cocoa Pods Spec Repo. To get the proper url to fetch this library.

CocoaPods Spec Repo have strict guidelines on accepting a library. You could read it on the sources I posted.

You could also deploy your own private Spec Repo:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods